# SQL merging 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I am new in db query coding, I did some google to find out how can I merge two tables in one but INNER JOIN and UNION ALL doing not exactly what I need.

I have 2 completely different tabels and I want it side by side in one

here is what I have:

```
+-----------+  +------------+
| ids type  |  | d1  d2  d3 |
+-----------+  +------------+
| 1   01    |  | 45  13  4  |
| 2   02    |  | 46  14  4  |
| 3   03    |  | 47  15  4  |
+-----------+  | 48  16  4  |
               +------------+
```

And I wanna get this:

```
+-----------------------+
| ids  type  d1  d2  d3 |
+-----------------------+
| 1    01    45  13  4  |
| 2    02    46  14  4  |
| 3    03    47  15  4  |
| NULL NULL  48  16  4  |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: is there any possibility that there can have many records on the left table than on the right table?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  And what determines the order -- ids and d1?

Comment: MSSQL, ids order is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you have no ke to join the table.  Assuming you are using a reasonable database, you can generate one using `row_number()`.  i am going to assume the first table is ordered by `ids` and the second by `d1`.

```
select t1.ids, t1.type, t2.d1, t2.d2, t2.d3
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by ids) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by d1) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
```

What this is doing is assigning a sequential number to each table, which is then used for the join.

Comment: @AshReva . . . No.  A cross join would create all combinations of rows in one table with rows in the other table.  That would generate 12 rows of output, none with NULLs in the column values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with a couple CTEs using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with cte1 as (
  select ids, type, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ids) rn
  from table1 
  ), cte2 as (
  select d1, d2, d3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d1) rn
  from table2 
  ) 
select t1.ids, t1.type, t2.d1, t2.d2, t2.d3
from cte1 t1 
  left join cte2 t2 on t1.rn=t2.rn
union 
select t1.ids, t1.type, t2.d1, t2.d2, t2.d3
from cte2 t2 
  left join cte1 t1 on t1.rn=t2.rn
where t1.ids is null
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42b381/5)